# convert a string (list) into an array then output to csv in more then one row

Tags: php, csv

I must arrange list of sites in order to handle updates more efficiently.

To do so I generate a list elsewhere (which must be in the format I will present) convert it into an array to scroll through the items easily, although that is done only after I shuffle the list first so I can randomly select 30 deferent sites out of that list and write them into a .CSV column (hopefully), then rinse and repeat i.e. Iterate back to last position of the ArrayIterator and take it from there, until the list is over, my goal is to write every 30 sites into their own column on the .CSV file.

So far I can’t get it to work. The CSV part that is the rest is fine, but on the CSV they all appear like this:

```
site1.com
site2.com
.
.
.
site1000.com
```

which should be:

```
site1.com            site31.com      site62
site30.com           site61.com      site92.com
```

I searched for this for while all over… can someone please check it out perhaps throw in a few line’s to finish this script of.. I think this shouldn’t be a such big deal for some one more experienced.

```
<?php
$list = 'site1.com
site2.com
.
.
.
site1000.com ';

$Sites = explode("\n",$list);
$Sites = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$Sites);
shuffle($Sites);
$Array_size = count($Sites);
foreach ($Sites as $U_val){
    $D++;
}
echo $D;
echo '<br><hr>';
$Sites = new NoRewindIterator(new ArrayIterator($Sites));
$i =0;
for($R=0;$R<=$D;$R++){
    Run($Sites);
}   
function Run($array){
    $fp = fopen('S_list.csv', 'a+');
    foreach ($array as  $val){
    $amount_to_run = 20;
    $i++;
    if($i<=$amount_to_run){
        $Write = explode("\n",$val);
        $Write = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$Write);
        fputcsv($fp, $Write);
    } else{
        echo '<br><hr>';
        break;
    }
    close($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# args

/** 
 * List of sites
 * @var string 
 */
 $sSites = '...';

 $nChunkSize = 30;

 $sTargetFileName = 'target.csv'; 

 # code

 $aSites = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $sSites));

 $aResult = array();

 shuffle($aSites);

 foreach (array_chunk($aSites, $nChunkSize) as $aRow){

   $aResult[] = implode(',',$aRow);

 } // foreach

 file_put_contents($sTargetFileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $aResult));
```

Comment: Nice!!! Thanks so much!!! 
To any one that may use this the last line of the fixed code is missing a closeing ). 

should be :  


file_put_contents($sTargetFileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $aResult));